# How can i display all columns in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to show all columns of dataframe in a google colab containing null value. Colab shows some of the columns and showing dots in the middle , and continue displaying columns again to last few columns.

[image]

How can I display all columns?

Comment: Can you try `data.columns` or `print(data.columns)`?

Comment: well it show all columns index but i want to show the null value also

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas to manipulate data, and want to display all columns, please refer to [Haddock-san's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75110797/7789963).

However, if you want to display all rows resulting from `df.isnull.sum()` or otherwise, you can use [`pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html?highlight=pandas) to achieve the desired output:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# generate reproducible data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12)

df = pd.DataFrame([rng.choice(a=[5, None], size=100)])
print(df.isnull().sum())
```

Output:

```
0     1
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     0
     ..
95    1
96    1
97    1
98    1
99    1
Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

**Solution**:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# remaining code from above to count the number
# of missing elements in each column in df
```

Output:

```
0     1
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    1
13    1
14    1
15    0
16    0
17    1
18    0
19    1
20    1
21    0
22    0
23    1
24    0
25    0
26    1
27    0
28    0
29    0
30    0
31    0
32    1
33    0
34    1
35    1
36    0
37    0
38    1
39    0
40    1
41    1
42    1
43    1
44    0
45    1
46    1
47    1
48    0
49    0
50    1
51    1
52    0
53    1
54    0
55    1
56    1
57    0
58    1
59    0
60    1
61    1
62    1
63    1
64    0
65    1
66    1
67    0
68    1
69    0
70    0
71    1
72    1
73    0
74    0
75    1
76    1
77    0
78    0
79    1
80    0
81    0
82    0
83    0
84    1
85    0
86    1
87    1
88    1
89    1
90    0
91    1
92    1
93    1
94    1
95    1
96    1
97    1
98    1
99    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: OP asked for columns, not rows.

Comment: @Haddock-san You are right - hope the edited answer is helpful for OP as well.